# Чем отличается Set от HashSet?

Tags: java

И еще, кто нибудь может подробно объяснить чем отличается `Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();` и `HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();`?

Comment: Вопросы использования функций сайта следует задавать [на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.util.Set` - интерфейс, а не класс.
`HashSet` имплементирует интерфейс `Set`.
`Set set1 = new HashSet();` создает объект типа `HashSet` и присваивает ссылку на объекту переменной типа `Set`.

`HashSet set1 = new HashSet();` создает объект типа `HashSet` и присваивает ссылку на объекту переменной типа `HashSet`.

Т.е эти два примеры инициализации отличаются способом хранения `HashSet`.Например, инициализация `Set set1 = new HashSet();` позволяет "переделать" `HashSet` в `TreeSet`.

P.S. Забыл добавить, что в ООП считается хорошим тоном объявлять переменные с типом интерфейса, т.к. код нужно писать в наиболее общем виде.